# Update table based on Criteria in joined tables

Tags: sql-server

I have the following

Customers 1-Many CustomerAddresses

Customers 1-Many CustomerCalls

I want to update CustomerAddresses based on the value in a column in CustomerCalls.  Something like the following:

```
Update CustomerAddresses
Set CustomerAddresses.PostCode = 'xxx'
Where CustomerCalls.CallType = 'x'
```

Comment: What is your question? DO you need to use `UPDATE FROM`? to create the `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `from` clause in your update statement, allowing you to also use joins. Something like this should do the trick (though I had to guess the column names...)

```
UPDATE CustomerAddresses
SET CustomerAddresses.PostCode = 'xxx'
FROM CustomerAddresses 
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.Address = CustomerAddresses.AddressId
INNER JOIN CustomerCalls ON Customers.Calls = CustomerCalls.CallId
WHERE CustomerCalls.CallType = 'x'
```